# Get checked inputs from inputs in a jQuery object

Tags: jquery, html

If I do this:

```
var inputs = $('input[name="ch_attachments[featured][]"]');
```

How do I find inputs that are checked from the object `inputs`?

I've tried:

```
var checked_inputs = $(inputs, ":checked");
```

and

```
var checked_inputs = $(inputs).find(":checked");
```

Both didn't work. Before you answer I cannot use

```
var checked_inputs = $('input[name="ch_attachments[featured][]"]:checked');
```

as this processing is done in a function where only `inputs` is passed so I need to find the checked inputs from only using the object `inputs`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter` for this.

http://jsfiddle.net/Xgv8C/2

```
var $inputs = $('input[name="ch_attachments[featured][]"]');
$inputs = $inputs.filter(':checked');
alert($inputs.length);
​
```